# how to join 3 tables with laravel?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I have the 3 tables below:

Users:
id,name,password,...

Reviews:
id,comment,userId, placeId

FoodAndDrinks:
id, name, ...

I need to join the tables as below:

FoodAndDrinks --> Reviews --> Users

Below are my codes - the link between FoodAndDrinks And Reviews are fine. I am having trouble to link to Users:

FoodAndDrink.php

```
class Foodanddrink extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'foodanddrinks';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    function reviews(){
        return $this ->hasMany(Review::class,'placeId');
    }

    function users(){
        return $this ->hasMany(User::class,'userId');
    }
}
```

Review.php

```
class Review extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reviews';

    use HasFactory;

    public function users(){
        return $this ->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    
}
```

User.php

```
function reviews(){
    return $this ->hasMany(Review::class,'userId');
}
```

I try to access users.name as below:

```
@foreach($data->reviews as $x)
  {{ $x->users->name}}
```

But this returns an error:

> Attempt to read property "name" on null

What am I missing out?

Comment: what is $x? what class?

Comment: it's just an alias.

Comment: Can you please var_dump($data->reviews); and show the results?

Comment: @avdeveloper is not an alias, is a Review, because `$data->reviews` is a Review Collection. Anyway `users` method (relation) in Review class seems to miss the parameter for the key, like in the other model? I will change to hasOne also

Comment: Did you tried   `public function users(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Review::class, 'placeId', 'id', 'id', 'userId');
    }`  in Foodanddrink  model?